# How to use Salesforce2Salesforce to collaborate on cases?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

We have two partners from two organizations who both have a Salesforce account (Entreprise Editions).

The two would like to collaborate on `customer cases` that are related to both of them.

I checked `Salesforce to Salesforce` ([Link](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce)), but am not sure whether `Subscribing` and `Publishing` make it possible to work on one item together.

What would be the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 1):

So it depends on the details. You can push (Publishing) objects/fields to a connection. The connection (your partner) then needs to receive (subscribe) to create the case. There is setup on both ends.

The challenge with cases is the lookup fields. If you're not sharing the same Accounts and Contacts with Salesforce to Salesforce you cannot fill in the look up fields. The ID of the account is not the same account in your partner's database. To compensate you can either share all Account/cases -- or you  can create formula fields that will display the name of the account/contact and any other available information. Your partner will then have to use that information to determine the correct records for their look up fields.

Once you have the connection setup you mark you want to sync a particular case. After that, it's up to your partners to accept the record and have the right fields subscribed and mapped